# Bulk Import files on Media Library from CSV

Tags: media-library, bulk-import

I have a list of more than 5000 files (pdf, doc, jpg ...) on an external server that I would like to upload my Wordpress media library. I would raise them with its corresponding title and description, and I have all that information in a csv (file url, title and description). I leave an example:

[image: csv example]

Is there any way? The closest thing to what I want is the WP All Import plugin, but does not support media library.

Thank you.

Comment: Anyone can help me? : '(

Comment: I can't believe this simple need goes 8 years without a good answer. I am so sorry I went with Wordpress. Only with wordpress could avoiding 6 tedious hours of manual work cause you to spend 12 fruitless hours of scouring the internet for nonexistent answers to simple, common-sense needs.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem. The closest solution I can think of is a little hacky, and it definitely is not great if you will be doing this import often.

My solution is to use WP All Import to import new posts for each image, so that each image gets uploaded to your media library. This will also create 5000 garbage posts, but you can delete them afterwards. I would suggest uploading the new posts as drafts so that they don't appear on the website when you do the import.

Let me know if you found a better solution.